# How do I implement a useEffect cleanup function in my code to fix the listed error?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, react-hook-form

**Edit: The first question was answered, but the second was not.**

I am creating an app using React, Material UI, React Hook Form, and Yup.

I have two dialogs, one for the "edit dose" button and the "delete med" button for each card. On the "edit dose" dialog, the user inputs a new dose into a form. However, I am having two problems with this.

1. No matter which card's button I press, the console is logging that the medication.id passed into the updateDose function is the id of the last displayed card.
2. I am getting the following warning if I try to update a medication more than once (the first update shows no error, and then the second shows this)...

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

Can you please help me identify why these things are happening and how I can fix them?  Below is my relevant code...

```
export default function DisplayMedications() {

    // This handles the delete medication confirmation dialog
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false); 
    const handleClickOpen = () => {
        setOpen(true); 
    }; 
    const handleClose = () => {
        setOpen(false); 
    };
    
    // This handles the update medication dialog 
    const [openUpdate, setOpenUpdate] = useState(false); 
    const handleClickOpenUpdate = () => {
        setOpenUpdate(true); 
    }; 
    const handleCloseUpdate = () => {
        setOpenUpdate(false); 
    };
    
    // Function for the delete med button
    function deleteMedication(medicationId, parsedMedications) {
        if (parsedMedications.length > 1) {
            parsedMedications.splice(medicationId, 1);
        } else {
            parsedMedications = [];
        }
    
        localStorage.setItem("medications", JSON.stringify(parsedMedications));
    
        // This forces the dialog to close
        setOpen(false); 
    }
    
    // Function for the update dose button
    function updateDose(medicationId, parsedMedications, data) {
        parsedMedications[medicationId].dose = data.dose;
        localStorage.setItem("medications", JSON.stringify(parsedMedications));
    
        // This forces the dialog to close
        setOpenUpdate(false); 
    }
    
   // This is the data that I am using to create the cards
   let medicationList = localStorage.getItem("medications");
   let parsed = JSON.parse(medicationList);

   medications = parsed.map((medication) => {
        return (
            <Box key={medication.id}>
                <Card sx={cardSx}>
                    <CardContent>
                        <Typography sx={typographyMedicationSx} variant="h5">
                            Medication: {medication.medication}
                        </Typography>
                        <Typography sx={typographyMedicationSx} variant="h5">
                            Dose: {medication.dose} mg
                        </Typography>
                    </CardContent>
                    <Box>
                        <Button onClick={handleClickOpenUpdate} size="large" sx={buttonSx} variant="contained">Edit
                            Dose</Button>
                        <Button onClick={handleClickOpen} color="error"
                                size="large"
                                sx={buttonSx} variant="contained">Delete
                            Med</Button>
                    </Box>
                </Card>

                {/* Delete medication dialog */}
                <Box>
                    <Dialog
                        open={open}
                        onClose={handleClose}
                        TransitionComponent={Transition}
                    >
                        <Typography variant="h5" sx={{m: 5}}> Are you sure you want to delete the
                            medication? </Typography>

                        <Box>
                            <Button onClick={() => deleteMedication(medication.id, parsed)} size="large"
                                    sx={buttonSx} variant="contained">Yes</Button>
                            <Button color="error"
                                    size="large"
                                    sx={buttonSx} variant="contained">No</Button>
                        </Box>
                    </Dialog>
                </Box>

                {/* Update medication dialog */}
                <Box>
                    <Dialog
                        open={openUpdate}
                        onClose={handleCloseUpdate}
                        TransitionComponent={Transition}
                    >
                        <DialogTitle sx={dialogTitleSx}>
                            {handleCloseUpdate ? (
                                <IconButton
                                    aria-label="close"
                                    onClick={handleCloseUpdate}
                                    sx={iconButtonSx}
                                >
                                    <CloseIcon/>
                                </IconButton>
                            ) : null}
                        </DialogTitle>

                        <form
                            onSubmit={handleSubmit((data) => updateDose(medication.id, parsed, data))}
                            noValidate>
                            <Typography sx={updateDoseTypography} variant="h4">
                                Update dose
                            </Typography>

                            <Box
                                sx={boxSx}
                            >
                                <Controller
                                    name="dose"
                                    control={control}
                                    defaultValue={""}
                                    render={({field: {ref, ...field}, fieldState: {error}}) => (
                                        <Autocomplete
                                            {...field}
                                            autoHighlight
                                            disableClearable
                                            isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.id === value.id}
                                            id="dose-autocomplete"
                                            onChange={(event, value) => field.onChange(value.label)}
                                            options={doseSuggestions}
                                            renderInput={(params) => (
                                                <TextField
                                                    required
                                                    error={!!error}
                                                    helperText={error?.message}
                                                    id="dose"
                                                    label="Dose"
                                                    name="dose"
                                                    type="numeric"
                                                    inputRef={ref}
                                                    {...params}
                                                />
                                            )}
                                        />
                                    )}
                                />

                                <Button disabled={!formState.isValid} size="large" sx={formButtonSx} type="submit"
                                        variant="contained">Submit</Button>
                            </Box>
                        </form>
                    </Dialog>
                </Box>
            </Box>
        )
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `unmounted component` in error #2 is your `Box` to display the `updateDost` form

I think the mistake you have made is not decoupling the `<MedicationContainer/>` and each single `<Medication/>` component. So what ends up happening is that even if you change the state of a single `<Medication/>` component, you re-render the entire list with a partial state-change.

The 1st time your when you call `updateDose`, it works just fine because only the initial component state has been loaded. When you do call it the 2nd time, i.e. once the component has already been re-rendered due to a partial state change,

Hence, to systematically solve your error, you can do this :

```
export default function DisplayMedications() {
    
   // This is the data that I am using to create the cards
   let medicationList = localStorage.getItem("medications");
   let parsed = JSON.parse(medicationList);

   return parsed.map((medication) => {
        <Medication medication = {medication} medications={medications} />
    });
```

And your separately managed `Medication` component

```
const Medication = ({medication}) => {

  // This handles the delete medication confirmation dialog
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false); 
    const handleClickOpen = () => {
        setOpen(true); 
    }; 
    const handleClose = () => {
        setOpen(false); 
    };
    
    // This handles the update medication dialog 
    const [openUpdate, setOpenUpdate] = useState(false); 
    const handleClickOpenUpdate = () => {
        setOpenUpdate(true); 
    }; 
    const handleCloseUpdate = () => {
        setOpenUpdate(false); 
    };
    
    // Function for the delete med button
    function deleteMedication(medicationId, parsedMedications) {
        if (parsedMedications.length > 1) {
            parsedMedications.splice(medicationId, 1);
        } else {
            parsedMedications = [];
        }
    
        localStorage.setItem("medications", JSON.stringify(parsedMedications));
    
        // This forces the dialog to close
        setOpen(false); 
    }
    
    // Function for the update dose button
    function updateDose(medicationId, parsedMedications, data) {
        console.log(medicationId);
        console.log(data);
    
        parsedMedications[medicationId].dose = data.dose;
        localStorage.setItem("medications", JSON.stringify(parsedMedications));
    
        // This forces the dialog to close
        setOpenUpdate(false); 
    }



  return (

   <Box key={medication.id}>
                <Card sx={cardSx}>
                    <CardContent>
                        <Typography sx={typographyMedicationSx} variant="h5">
                            Medication: {medication.medication}
                        </Typography>
                        <Typography sx={typographyMedicationSx} variant="h5">
                            Dose: {medication.dose} mg
                        </Typography>
                    </CardContent>
                    <Box>
                        <Button onClick={handleClickOpenUpdate} size="large" sx={buttonSx} variant="contained">Edit
                            Dose</Button>
                        <Button onClick={handleClickOpen} color="error"
                                size="large"
                                sx={buttonSx} variant="contained">Delete
                            Med</Button>
                    </Box>
                </Card>

                {/* Delete medication dialog */}
                <Box>
                    <Dialog
                        open={open}
                        onClose={handleClose}
                        TransitionComponent={Transition}
                    >
                        <Typography variant="h5" sx={{m: 5}}> Are you sure you want to delete the
                            medication? </Typography>

                        <Box>
                            <Button onClick={() => deleteMedication(medication.id, parsed)} size="large"
                                    sx={buttonSx} variant="contained">Yes</Button>
                            <Button color="error"
                                    size="large"
                                    sx={buttonSx} variant="contained">No</Button>
                        </Box>
                    </Dialog>
                </Box>

                {/* Update medication dialog */}
                <Box>
                    <Dialog
                        open={openUpdate}
                        onClose={handleCloseUpdate}
                        TransitionComponent={Transition}
                    >
                        <DialogTitle sx={dialogTitleSx}>
                            {handleCloseUpdate ? (
                                <IconButton
                                    aria-label="close"
                                    onClick={handleCloseUpdate}
                                    sx={iconButtonSx}
                                >
                                    <CloseIcon/>
                                </IconButton>
                            ) : null}
                        </DialogTitle>

                        <form
                            onSubmit={handleSubmit((data) => updateDose(medication.id, parsed, data))}
                            noValidate>
                            <Typography sx={updateDoseTypography} variant="h4">
                                Update dose
                            </Typography>

                            <Box
                                sx={boxSx}
                            >
                                <Controller
                                    name="dose"
                                    control={control}
                                    defaultValue={""}
                                    render={({field: {ref, ...field}, fieldState: {error}}) => (
                                        <Autocomplete
                                            {...field}
                                            autoHighlight
                                            disableClearable
                                            isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.id === value.id}
                                            id="dose-autocomplete"
                                            onChange={(event, value) => field.onChange(value.label)}
                                            options={doseSuggestions}
                                            renderInput={(params) => (
                                                <TextField
                                                    required
                                                    error={!!error}
                                                    helperText={error?.message}
                                                    id="dose"
                                                    label="Dose"
                                                    name="dose"
                                                    type="numeric"
                                                    inputRef={ref}
                                                    {...params}
                                                />
                                            )}
                                        />
                                    )}
                                />

                                <Button disabled={!formState.isValid} size="large" sx={formButtonSx} type="submit"
                                        variant="contained">Submit</Button>
                            </Box>
                        </form>
                    </Dialog>
                </Box>
            </Box>

  )



}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that helped a lot! Now the cards are correctly updating/deleting. However, I am still getting that same warning. What do you mean that the unmounted component is the Box with my updateDose form?

Comment: The "unmounted component" your 2nd error talks of is the "Box" component containing the form whose submission is handled by the "updateDose" method

Answer (score 1):

1. The warning in the 2nd part is actually occurring because of the way you have handled the `<DialogTitle sx={dialogTitleSx}>` you have called for the "Box" component representing the Update medication dialog.
2. You have called the `handleCloseUpdate` method for rendering this  .
3. `handleCloseUpdate` is a function that sets the state for opening the `update model` by calling the setter `setOpenUpdate(false)` in its body
4. However, your when your `Box` component itself is unmounted i.e. it's not rendered to screen because you haven't opened the `updateModal` yet, hence React throws an error saying - "You can't update state from an unmounted component"
5. This warning is important since anyways your `handleCloseUpdate` does a state update and does not return some result on the basis of which you can run JSX logic

The corrected code here would be :

```
                        <DialogTitle sx={dialogTitleSx}>
                            {openUpdate ? (
                                <IconButton
                                    aria-label="close"
                                    onClick={handleCloseUpdate}
                                    sx={iconButtonSx}
                                >
                                    <CloseIcon/>
                                </IconButton>
                            ) : null}
                        </DialogTitle>
```

Also, friendly tip, if you want to run any function each time the component loads, wrap it inside a `useEffect()` hook
Here, however, there's no need to run `handleCloseUpdate` when you're rendering the component and hence I have removed it from your JSX logic